# Why are services directory and arcgis manager not accessible?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I installed ArcGIS Server 10.0 for Java with its post install and its SP 5.

When I try to access the services directory, I get a 404 error from the web server. I don't get that error when I try to get to the arcgis manager web interface.

After displaying the arcgis manager web interface, when I try to login, I get an error: Login information is incorrect. The login used is arcgismanager that is member of agsadmin. The password used is the one specified in the post install.

Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ArcGIS Manager authentication problem, the solution is to deactivate Windows Firewalls.

For the services directory the solution is to make sure that the machine name declared in the configuration file of the web server installed by ArcGIS Server corresponds exactly to the machine name (capital letters). In my case, there was a confusion between small and capital letters.